# Select dropdown linking to Matrix blocks

Tags: templating, matrix

I need a little bit of assitance. I have a matrix block that outputs floorplans diagrams and it's specification per floor in a property (see screenshot attached below.

I've got the matrix fields outputting correctly on the page, but I need to get it to only output a single floor at a time, and not all floors, and then let the user click on a select dropdown to change to the floor level that they want to view.

Here's the current markup:

Hopefully someone can help to get it working?

```
<form class="form" action="{{ entry.url }}" method="get">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="selectwrap">
      <select id="development1" class="form-control" name="floor" onchange="this.form.submit()">
        <option value="">Select Floor</option>
        {% for block in entry.floorplans %}
        <option value="{{ block.floorplanlevel }}">{{ block.floorplanlevel.label }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>


{# Start Matrix Block #}
{% for block in entry.floorplans %} {# Main Field Handle #}
{% switch block.type %}

{% case "floorplan" %} {# Matrix Block Type Handle #}
......
```

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not related to Craft CMS specifically.

Comment: I disagree. The question is how can I link these matrix blocks to the drop down select. An answer would be appreciated

Comment: I disagree as well, the OP clearly mentions how Matrix plays into it. Voting to keep open.

Comment: It looks like you got a perfectly fine answer from @darylknight already in the comments to your related question http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/18565/how-to-approach-a-multi-level-floorplan/18566#18566, did you miss that?

Comment: It doesn't answer how to target the different floors created from the same matrix blocks which is the question

Answer (score 4):

Two options:

- Physically output all the floorplans in the markup `{% for block in entry.matrixHandle%}` then hide them using CSS, and only display the one from the dropdown using JavaScript. Something like `$('#dropdown-id).on('change', function(){});`
- Change the field from a Matrix so that each floorplan is a separate Entry and you visit each one with an `href="{{ entry.url }}`.

Comment: You should mention that you are talking about a JavaScript powered toggle implementation. Which is also the reason why it's not really a Craft specific problem to solve.

Comment: Can you mark this as solved if it answers the question @mention79?